# Signal R Native Android app Negotiation Failed

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm trying to create an android app that could connect to my basic SignalR Hub.

Its just a basic Hub file i want to test things out with but I've had no luck so far. Could someone have a look at the thing(s) I'm doing wrong? Every time I try to run it I get the following stackraces:

```
05-27 09:10:39.785  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.WebsocketTransport$1>
05-27 09:10:39.785  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.WebsocketTransport$1>
05-27 09:10:39.829  22247-22266/nl.vict.chatapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.WebsocketTransport$1>
05-27 09:10:39.830  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server
05-27 09:10:39.830  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture.get(SignalRFuture.java:112)
05-27 09:10:39.830  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture.get(SignalRFuture.java:102)
05-27 09:10:39.830  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at nl.vict.chatapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
05-27 09:10:39.831  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
05-27 09:10:39.831  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-27 09:10:39.832  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-27 09:10:39.832  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-27 09:10:39.832  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-27 09:10:39.833  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-27 09:10:39.833  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-27 09:10:39.833  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-27 09:10:39.833  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-27 09:10:39.834  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-27 09:10:39.834  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.HttpClientTransport$1.onResponse(HttpClientTransport.java:86)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.java.NetworkRunnable.run(NetworkRunnable.java:82)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.WebsocketTransport$1
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.WebsocketTransport.start(WebsocketTransport.java:92)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.AutomaticTransport.resolveTransport(AutomaticTransport.java:89)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.AutomaticTransport.start(AutomaticTransport.java:143)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Connection.startTransport(Connection.java:673)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Connection.access$500(Connection.java:30)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Connection$3.run(Connection.java:373)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Connection$3.run(Connection.java:350)
05-27 09:10:39.855  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture.setResult(SignalRFuture.java:73)
05-27 09:10:39.856  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.HttpClientTransport$1.onResponse(HttpClientTransport.java:82)
05-27 09:10:39.856  22247-22247/nl.vict.chatapp W/System.err﹕ ... 2 more
```

Here is my code:

Hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

Main Activity (Android Studio)

```
ListView listView;
    HubConnection connection;
    HubProxy proxy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] values = new String[]{
                "Testvalue1",
                "Testvalue2",
                "Testvalue3"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        connection = new HubConnection("http://www.voffice.nl/chat");
        proxy = connection.createHubProxy("chatHub");
        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start();
        try{
            awaitConnection.get();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ExecutionException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

Thanks in Advance,

Kevin

--

EDIT:

I've checked the server and websockets are enabled.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?I have a similar  (or the same) one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646442/signalr-android-access-localhost

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got it working after few days of struggle:

1. Download https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket and build it.
2. Download https://github.com/SignalR/java-client,
3. add libs folder to signalr-client-sdk and put `java_websocket.jar`
   that you built earlier
4. Replace in signalr-client-sdk/build.gradle

   `compile 'org.java-websocket:java-websocket:1.3.1'`

   with:

   `compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')`
5. Go here and find fix for http:// to ws:// url https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/issues/63, change it in code
6. Build signalr client and include it in your project, you also have to include `java_websocket.jar` that you built in first step, so your gradle file witll look like:

   `compile 'client.signalr.aspnet.microsoft.signalr_client_sdk_android:signalr-client-sdk-android-release:1.0.0@aar'
   compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
   compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')`

**Don't pass any querystring to HubConnection or it will hang!!**

If you need to pass headers (like authorization token) you have to fix some more code, there is pull request for this: https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/pull/64

Comment: could you explain why you replaced the websockets implementation with the one from TooTallNate?  can you also say whether you achieved an acceptable (i.e. production-ready) stable implementation in android ?